# Uploading multiple files with multer in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I was trying to allow uploading of multiple files to my express app but I fell into an error. What's wrong with this code?

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploaded");
  },

  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/upload_img", upload.single("fileupload"), (req, res, err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.redirect("/upload?upload success");
    console.log(req.files);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You specified:

```
upload.single('fileupload')
```

Change that to:

```
upload.array('fileupload')
```

Or you can also do this:

```
upload.any()
```

If you go with `upload.any()`, you can upload one file or multiple files, and you don't need to specify field name.